# why map output records and reduce input records in hadoop counter is different?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, counter

I run a word count job in hadoop 
my question is 
why map output records and reduce input records in hadoop counter is different ?
please see following image [image]

Answer (score 4):

According to the "Combine output records" counter, it seems that your job uses a combiner. That explains why "Reduce Input Records" is not equals to "Map out records".

The combiner has been fairly efficient by shrinking 100M records to a few hundreds.

Most likely, you will then ask why "Combine input records" is not equal to "Map output Records" and why "Combine output records" is not equal to "Record input records". The explanation is that combiners can be run multiple times meaning that you are "virtually" counting the same data several times (here you can observe that the 541 extra input records equals to 677 - 136 but it is not guaranteed that these two numbers will always match)

Answer (score 0):

I found this reason 
I used a combiner class in code